# Dynamically call method using reflection

Tags: java, reflection

I want to write a program which decides which methods to call on an object at runtime.

For example

```xml
 <method>getXyz<operation>
 <arg type="int"> 1 <arg>
 <arg type="float"> 1/0 <arg>
```

Now I have something like above in XML files and I want to decide which method to call at runtime. There can be multiple methods.

I don't want to do something like the following in my code:

```
 if (methodNam.equals("getXyz"))
     //call obj.getXyz()
```

How can I do it using Java reflection?

Also I want to construct the parameter list at runtime. For example, one method can take 
2 parameters and another can take `n` arguments.

Answer (score 2):

You should use [`Object.getClass()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass%28%29) method to get the [`Class`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) object first.

Then you should use [`Class.getMethod()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethod%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class...%29) and [`Class.getDeclaredMethod()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredMethod%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class...%29) to get the [`Method`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html), and finally use [`Method.invoke()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object...%29) to invoke this method.

Example:

```
public class Tryout {
    public void foo(Integer x) { 
        System.out.println("foo " + x);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Tryout myObject = new Tryout();
        Class<?> cl = myObject.getClass();
        Method m = cl.getMethod("foo", Integer.class);
        m.invoke(myObject, 5);
    }
}
```

> Also i want to construct the parameter list at runtime.For Example one
>   method can take 2 parameters and other can take n args

This is not an issue, just create *arrays* of `Class<?>` for the *types* of the arguments, and an array of `Object`s of the values of the arguments, and pass them to `getMethod()` and `invoke()`. It works because these methods accept `Class<?>...` as argument, and an array fits it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following code to a class method using reflection

```
package reflectionpackage;
public class My {
    public My() {
    }
   public void myReflectionMethod(){
        System.out.println("My Reflection Method called");
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, NoSuchMethodException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException
{
        Class c=Class.forName("reflectionpackage.My");
        Method m=c.getDeclaredMethod("myReflectionMethod");
        Object t = c.newInstance();
        Object o= m.invoke(t);       
    }
}
```

this will work and for further reference please follow the link
http://compilr.org/java/call-class-method-using-reflection/

Answer (score -1):

Have a good look at `java.beans.Statement` and `java.beans.Expression`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10009052/invoking-setter-method-using-java-reflection/10009255#10009255) for further details.